# what if retention.bytes is less than the segment.bytes?

Tags: apache-kafka

Will the segment be active or be closed when it reached the retention.bytes?

I didn't see any constraint for both configuration. I assume it can be any value.
I understand when it comes to time, if retention.ms is less than the log.roll.ms, the segment will not be close. Which one is prioritized in the .bytes scenario?

Comment: Start a broker locally and test some different options? What did you notice? In general, bytes are prioritized over time